# PDF doesn't show on APK build: Expo cli and react-native-pdf

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-pdf

I'm still learning React Native, and I've been working on a project that uses **react-native-pdf** with **expo-cli**. It works great in development mode, but when I try to build an APK, the PDF doesn't show up. I've tried changing the source type, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code or an sample.
Did you build a custom client  (https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf#supported-versions) ?